# Failed to install itcuties-data-usage-app.apk on device '0123456789ABCDEF': Connection refused: connect

Tags: android

I have developed an application . I have also connected a device with my laptop . But when I am trying to run application , I have got the following error .

```
[2015-05-07 16:38:52 - itcuties-data-usage-app] WARNING: Unknown device API version!
[2015-05-07 16:38:52 - itcuties-data-usage-app] Uploading itcuties-data-usage-app.apk onto device '0123456789ABCDEF'
[2015-05-07 16:17:01 - itcuties-data-usage-app] Failed to install itcuties-data-usage-app.apk on device '0123456789ABCDEF': Connection refused: connect
[2015-05-07 16:17:01 - itcuties-data-usage-app] java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
[2015-05-07 16:17:01 - itcuties-data-usage-app] Launch canceled!
```

I have tried for solution . I have set the ADB connection Time Out to 10000ms. But still the problem is not solved . Please help me .

[image]

Comment: In those cases I restart the related parties. Try this points until it works for you: restart adb, disable and reanable debugging on your target device, reboot the target device, reboot your computer.

Answer (score 1):

By following 3 points , I have solved this problem .

1. Restart adb
2. Restart phone
3. Restart PC